# Spring controller mapping doesn't match some URL encoded strings

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have this mapping:

```
@GetMapping("/{example}")
public void example(@PathVariable String example) {
   ...
}
```

The following URLs match and hit this method:

1. `/foo`
2. `/f%20oo`

These ones do not (I get a 404):

1. `/f%0Doo`
2. `/f%0Aoo`

Why not?

How can I match URLs containing these encoded characters?

**Edit**: I've had a look at `PathMatchConfigurer` but can't see where this behaviour is explained.

Comment: According to [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp), it seems that control characters have nothing to do inside a URL. `%0D` and `%0A` are control characters, I guess that's why they aren't handled by Spring's mapping.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but other characters in that same list (i.e. control characters) work just fine (i.e. do not result in a 404) e.g. `/f%01oo`. Also I do not understand what the page means by "nothing to do inside a URL". What is the purpose of having a URL encoding for a character if that encoding is not valid inside a URL?

Comment: For encoding the parameters e.g. `&param=f%0Doo`

Comment: Incidentally, %0A and %0D are "classic" chars "line feed" (LF) and "carriage return" (CR), commonly used to mark end of text lines. I must admit that finding a path inside a URI containing such chars is quite unusual. Since pattern matching normally doesn't span lookup on further lines (whose end is marked by %0A and/or %0D), it is possible that Spring doesnt' consider such kind of strings as valid for a URI.

Comment: If you can change your API rather put these values into request parameters, such as Google Translate API does: https://translate.google.de/?hl=de&tab=wT#auto/en/Wir%20hatten%0Agestern%20Fleischk%C3%BCchle%20%26%20Sauerkraut%2FGem%C3%BCse